Looking for the final page of the paper by Erdős et al., "Strong embeddings of graphs into colored graphs"
I am looking for the final page (page 595) of the paper by Erdős, Hajnal, and Pósa, "Strong embeddings of graphs into colored graphs," Infinite and finite sets (Colloq., Keszthely, 1973; dedicated to P. Erdős on his 60th birthday), Vols. I, II, III, pp. 585–595,
Colloq. Math. Soc. János Bolyai, Vol. 10, North-Holland, Amsterdam-London, 1975.
Two online sources I found only go up to page 594.
https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-44.pdf#page=10
I suspect that if I order it via a library, that's what they'll send me.
